# Should 3em font not be the same size as 3em div?

Tags: html, css, font-size

This is my code: http://jsbin.com/ziwafeyari/1/edit?html,css,output

Should the div not be the same size as the text? I know em's aren't specific values, they are relative to something, but to what?

Does the em size differ by .css file or by each tag (`div/p/ol/ul`)?

Comment: `em` is measured in relation to the parent, so can vary from element to element. root em or `rem` is like a global, so they will be the same size. if your global em for a font equals 16px, and the same for a div, then 3em will be 48px in either element.

Comment: so if I want all "em's" on my document to mean the same, I should just use "rem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 10px + .5em = 5px
- 10px + 1em = 10px
- 10px + 2em = 20px
- 10px + 50% = 5px
- 10px + 100% = 10px
- 10px + 200% = 20px

```css
.standard-size {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.standard-size-resized-with-em {
    font-size: .5em;
}

.standard-size-resized-with-percentage {
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-size">
    My text is 30px! <br />
 <span class="standard-size-resized-with-em" style="">My text is 15px!</span>
</div>

<div class="standard-size">
    My text is 30px! <br />
 <span class="standard-size-resized-with-percentage" style="">My text is 15px!</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v0Ladkun/5/

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! But there is still something I don't understand. Imagine that you have div C, which inside of div B, which is inside of div A. Div A font-size is 100px. Div B font-size is 0.5em. Div C font size is 0.5em. That means Div B font size is 50px. How about div c? 50px (A x 0.5) or 25px (B x 0.5)?

Comment: em and % ignore each other, including themselves. They only care about what the nearest px value is, if there is one. If a px value has not been set, the browser will select one by default.

Comment: On my comment I never used % so I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: em will only calculate from px value.

Answer (score 0):

1em is relative the size of the letter "m" in the current font. Hence "em", get it?

Comment: What does the "e" stand for? Or is it just how you pronounce "M" > "em"?

Answer (score 0):

`em` will inherit its parent's font-size. So if font-size is 1pt, `1em = 1pt`, `2em = 2pt`. If you haven't set font-size, by default it is 12pt or 16px. So default value of `em` is 12pt. It may vary in other HTML elements.

For more detailed information about `em`, visit [this link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thank you. What is considered a parent though? The tag which it is inside of (first-level) or all the tags which it is inside of (including html and body)?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. But what if I want one of the "ems" to be related to the body size? Will "rem" work for that?

Comment: rem is a new feature in CSS3 and stands for "root em" . In most HTML documents, <html> is root element. So, with rem keyword you can use declared size in html tag (root element) for any other element like this: html { font-size: 10px; } div { font-size: 2.4rem; } / * =24px */.